# Replace(), replacing a value not specified

Tags: javascript, string, methods, logical-operators

I've been learning Javascript via FCC for 6 weeks now, and decided to spend a week learning, and playing around with methods to get really close and comfortable with using them in loops, and with statements.  Just playing around with strings, I was trying to replace the string "I like milk", with "I like silk".  My code accomplishes this, and I understand it, but I decided to add an `||` operator, and the outcome bewilders me.  If i say `if(x[i]=== 'm' || x[i] === 'I'`, it doesn't replace `'I'`, but replaces `'m'` If i leave it the way it is in my original code, it produces the string `'I lise milk'`, even though `'k'` was never mentioned.  What is going on?

```
let x = 'Hello I like milk';
let y = '';

for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i] === 'm' || 'I') {
      y =  x.replace(x[i], 's' )
    }
}
console.log(y)
```

Comment: The expression `x[i] === 'm' || 'I'` is always true.  It first checks `x[i]=== 'm'`, which may be true or false, then you have an 'or' operator, and then the string literal `'I'`. That string literal is always truthy, so the 'or' operator will evaluate to true, and so it is always true.

Comment: This may help explain that more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy

Comment: I totally understand that, made that mistake the other day and learned my lesson.  I'm confused as to why exactly it replaces 'k' though?  As you can see in my question, i've tried fixing that, and it still does not replace 'I', but replaces 'm', even though 'I' is first in the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, there are a couple of gotchas that make your code interesting

1. `x[i] === 'm' || 'I'` is always true, because `'I'` is truthy - if that's not clear, you can test this with `if ('I') { console.log('Merry Christmas') }`
2. your loop produces a new string with one replacement every loop, i.e. it produces the same result as no loop and

   `y = x.replace(x[x.length - 1], 's')`
3. the replace will replace the first matching character - the last character in your string is `k`, so the replace will change the first matching `k` to `s`

so, the result of your code is

```
'Hello I lise milk'
```

Hope that helps clear things up!

btw, the easiest way to replace all `m`s and `I`s with an `s`:

```
console.log(x.replace(/[mI]/g, 's'))
```

Comment: It does for the most part, thanks for the explanation, I still do not understand how k is relevant when I haven't specified it, reading through w3schools documentation, it makes no mention of "the last character of the string"

Comment: it's because `x[i] === 'm' || 'I'` is always true!

Comment: It's just not landing, I understand  that my statement is always true, just cant figure out WHY it specifically replaces K. I just watched Idiocracy, and all I can think when I try to comprehend what you're saying is "it's got electrolytes".  I obviously need to understand this more haha!

Comment: ok, I like the challenge of learning how to be a better mentor, so I'm happy to keep trying different avenues until it's clear. Since we know that the predicate (if statement) is always true, we can just remove it from the code. On each iteration of the loop, the previously calculated `y` is discarded. The last time the loop is evaluated is on the last letter in `x`, which is `k`. Make sense?

Comment: Yep, was just ready to throw my computer out the window, when I realized that it was this simple.  I make this mistake A LOT of not updating a value in a loop, this is where things start getting frustrating, exactly why I decided to take a week off from learning, and start playing and breaking stuff.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help... keep plugging away, the initial ramp up of the learning curve is always the toughest... :fistbump

Answer (score 2):

So you basically are running into an issue with the way your code is flowing.

Let's start with issue one: Why is the m being overwritten but not the y?

So basically you have var x and y that you are updating throughout your loop.

The way your code works is basically: If the letter equals m or I replace it with an s.

The problem you are going to have here however is you never store the value that has since been updated. So when it loops again it is taking the default value of x (which hasn't actually been updated) and is writing it to y. This is going to overwrite the value each time.

We can demo this by simply logging inside of the loop.

```js
let x = 'Hello I like milk';
let y = '';

for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i] === 'm' || x[i] === 'I') {
      y =  x.replace(x[i], 's' )
      console.log(y)
    }
}
```

So if you run the above, you will see two lines being outputted.

1. Hello s like milk
2. Hello I like milk

The m is the only one being printed however because the log is after the final update.

So the next issue: Why is replacing that k?

As another commented posted, "I" is always going to be truthy. Truthy basically means the value isn't null, undefined, 0 etc. "I" has a value which means it will always be true.

So is the K being replaced? Well if we run that code, the final letter being checked and replaced is a k. .replace only replaces (by default) the first instance of that letter it comes across. In your case, that K is the first K that is seen.

So to fix it, don't check on "I" check: x[i] === "I"

EDIT: To answer your question about why the last letter matters

So the last letter matters here because you have what basically equates to:

```
if("I"){}
```

So that above snippet, contrary to what you may think actually means if this has a value, which because I is a valid character, will always report true. So for your loop, everything is actually being checked, regardless of the character because I is always going to be true.

Here is an easy way to check it:

Lets say I have an array of integers from 1 to 10. I have (pseudo code):

if array value < 10 OR I
   Print that value

With the way you are currently thinking, you would expect it to stop printing if the values are less than 10 right? Nope! Once again because I is always truthy and we are saying OR the value I (true) so we are going to always get a print!

Code example:

```js
var x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 , 50, 60, 70, 80];

    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       if(x[i] < 10 || "I") {
           console.log(x[i]);
       }
    }
```

See? Everything prints out! Even though half of the values are over 10 they are still printing out. Why? Because "I" is always true! Now let's edit that a bit to make it a bit more strict in checking:

```js
let x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 , 50, 60, 70, 80];

    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       if(x[i] < 10 || x[i] === "I") {
           console.log(x[i]);
       }
    }
```

See? Much better :)

Comment: Thanks you answer helped a lot, I still don't understand why the last letter of the string has any relevance here, but since it's mentioned in 2 answers, obviously i'm missing something here.

Comment: @Adag89 added another edit to help explain further, hope it helps.

Comment: I just realized what I wasn't understanding, haha!  Sry for making something so simple so complicated.